# Rails - Single User Multiple "Roles?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having an invoice model which belongs to user, and a user table that associates a user as a particular role or multiple roles:

```
class CreateInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
create_table :invoices do |t|
  t.string :po_number
  t.datetime :invoice_date
  t.datetime :date_received
  t.datetime :date_approved
  t.text :clerk_note
  t.integer :clerk_id
  t.integer :approver_id
  t.text :approver_note
end
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.boolean :account_clerk
      t.boolean :approver
      t.boolean :admin
    end
  end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :invoices
end
```

In the invoice record, how do I assign an clerk_id and approver_id depending on the role set in the user model?  Each invoice will have a clerk and approver, but both are users.

Likewise, how do I assign the clerk_note to the clerk_id and the approver_note to the approver_id?  I'm assuming in this case, I can just refer to current_user, since the user logged in will be the one making the note, right?

I'm not sure what this is called, so in my Googling, I didn't know what to look for... thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You might actually want to split the clerk and approver columns from the invoice table and create a invoice_users table that has the following columns: invoice_id, user_id, note, role.  Not sure if the same user can both be the approver and clerk in your system.

Comment: Thanks for that idea - yes, a user can be either or both approver/clerk.  I may use this approach... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question using your current models you can just create your view to display different fields based on the role of the user (this assumes the logged in user is in an instance variable named @user).

```
<% if (@user.approver) then %>
   <%= f.text_area :approver_note %>
<% else %>
   <%= f.text_area :clerk_note %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller you can set the value of clerk id or approver id again depending on the logged in user.

```
if (@user.approver) then
  @invoice.approver_id = @user.id
else
  @invoice.clerk_id = @user.id
end
```